# Android: Dynamically created table row is being deleted on screen rotate

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

From what I have read online, any dynamically created views should be saved when the android screen is rotated as long as those views are given an arbitrary id.

I am running into a problem, however, where any dynamically created table row that is created is deleted when the screen changes orientation from portrait to landscape or vice versa.

I have a TableLayout defined in my main activity's fragment which is modified after an activity where the user defines the data for a new table row finishes.

So far that part works fine.

The table stores an item and a corresponding location. itemInsertResponse is called by onActivityResult, which appends the new row returned by createItemRow to the existing table.

```
public void itemInsertResponse(Intent data) {
    String item = data.getStringExtra("item");
    String location = data.getStringExtra("location");

    TableLayout itemCatalog = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_catalog);
    itemCatalog.addView(createItemRow(item, location), new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


}

public TableRow createItemRow(String item, String location) {
    TableRow itemRow = new TableRow(this);
    itemRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    TextView itemText = new TextView(this);
    TextView locationText = new TextView(this);
    itemText.setText(item);
    itemText.setId(3);
    locationText.setId(4);

    locationText.setText(location);

    itemRow.addView(itemText);
    itemRow.addView(locationText);


    //setPadding appears to take values in px, need to conver to dp
    int padding_in_dp = 5;  // 6 dps
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding_in_px = (int) (padding_in_dp * scale + 0.5f);
    itemRow.setPadding(padding_in_px, padding_in_px, padding_in_px, padding_in_px);
    itemRow.setId(9001);

    return itemRow;

}
```

I set id values for the table row and the text views which, from what I have read, should mean that the default implementation of OnSavedInstanceState saves them.

Is this some kind of bug, or do I actually need to manually save the newly created rows in OnSavedInstanceState in order to maintain the state of the table?  If I do need to override that method, how do I save every dynamically created row?

The best solution I can think of is to store a global ArrayList of arrays containing the two strings for each row and then recreate every row in OnCreate using that ArrayList--but that's clearly very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pass views when saving state. When you are saving the state, you only have to pass some generated data, for example the `ArrayList` as you've mentioned and then recreate views let's say in `onCreate()` - if the `savedInstanceState` exists.

Btw, it seems like you don't care about that data for example if the app closes. If you would save it to a database or something then you would be able to easily read it when recreating.

Comment: Well, I do want to save it to a database eventually.  But I would probably read from and write to the database during the onPause and onResume life cycle events.

It seems too slow to do that every time the screen changes orientation and it doesn't seem necessary.  When the table layout is already loaded in memory, why waste processing time reading from the database and building it again?

Comment: @programmer-plebeian When the screen rotates, the activity gets completely destroyed. It calls onStop() and then again starts from onCreate().. you save data that you want to pass in onSaveInstanceState() and read it from the bundle in onCreate().. now what you can do is just store data in db as you insert it, but also pass it when recreated, and then in onCreate() you check if you have data in savedInstanceState, and if not - read it from database.